# TypeScript relative path import not working in Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

I imported a module in TypeScript using a relative path.

```
// index.ts
import {Widget} from './components/Widget';
```

Webpack gives me the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Widget' in 
C:\project\src' @ ./src/index.ts 4:19-51
```

My webpack config file is pretty basic, with the ts-loader in the rules and pointing to index.ts as the entry file.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Additional information:**

Project folder structure:

```
c:\project
├─ src
│  ├─ index.ts
│  └─ components
│     └─ Widget.ts
├─ webpack.config.js
└─ tsconfig.json
```

Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "include": [ "src/**/*" ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Versions:

```
webpack 3.1.0
typescript 2.4.1
ts-loader 2.2.2
```

Comment: Where is your `webpack.config.js` file located?

Comment: @Saravana I've added the info to the project structure in the answer.

Comment: Can you post your `tsconfig.json`? This should work as long as you don't have any path mapping in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: @Saravana Add tsconfig. The project builds perfectly find with the TypeScript compiler (tsc).

Comment: did you export Widget class in Widget.ts?also i which file are you trying to import your class ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `resolve.extensions` to your webpack.config.js.

```
{
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
    }
}
```

Module resolution in webpack defaults to searching only for `.js` and `.json` files when you write an extension-less import in one of your modules ([ref](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions)).

So when you write:

```
import {Widget} from './components/Widget';
```

Webpack only searches for these files by default:

```
./components/Widget.js
./components/Widget.json
```

and thus ends up giving the `Module not found` error.