# Testcafe Studio imports not working in Typescript

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

In Testcafe Studio importing works for Javascript, but not Typescript. I'm following the [example](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/use-page-model), just with Typescript.

*page-model.ts*

```
export default class Page {}
```

*tests.ts*

```
import * as page from './page-model';
```

The import string is underlined with an error:

> Cannot find module './page-model' or its corresponding type declarations.(2307)

What else is needed to make it work?

I considered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406372/typescript-relative-path-import-not-working-in-webpack), but even Javascript file imports show the same error.

Maybe it's related to a configuration [Note](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402659/reference/testcafe-api/runner/compileroptions):

> TestCafe resolves user-specified relative paths against the TestCafe installation folder.

**EDIT**
The whole question is about Testcafe *Studio*, I did not realize the distinction until just now. Updated question and tags.

Comment: I tried creating a TypeScript test file that imports a `*.ts` module in TestCafe Studio. I reproduced the behavior when the import line is underlined and an error hint is displayed.

However, when I run a test with an underlined import statement, it completes successfully without errors. Could you please clarify if this issue prevents your tests from running, or you only see a misleading error message.

Comment: @vasily.strelyaev You are correct! The underlined error does not happen at runtime. The errors I was getting at runtime were different, caused by the wrong export statement (I was exporting a type instead of an instance).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have created a ticket about the misleading error in our internal issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

I used [this example](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/use-page-model), rewrote it with TypeScript, and ran it. As a result, the test was successfully completed.

Make sure that the path to your file with the page model in the test file is correct.

Also, you import the Page by default, which means that you do not need to export it with `*`. Just export it as follows: `import page from './page-model';`

Comment: I realized I was using Testcafe Studio, not just Testcafe. Did you try it in the studio? My files are in the same dir with .ts extensions.